# React router - #/ getting added to query paramter

Tags: reactjs, connected-react-router

In my react application if I am sending a query parameter like `localhost:8000/?param1=value1`, it gets converted to `localhost:8000/?param1=value1#/`. I am new to this not really sure how it works. ConnectedRouter is being used :

```
<Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={hashHistory}>
          <AppRouter />
       </ConnectedRouter>
 </Provider>


 const AppRouter = () => (
  <Switch>
    <Route ...... />
    <Route ...... />
    .....
  </Switch>
);
```

Comment: by sending you mean making a get/post query ? how do you do it ?

Comment: Seems strange to be using `hashHistory` as it's a history implementation only intended for legacy (old) browsers. Also you're creating your own router component called `AppRouter` inside of another router component - those are probably interfering with each other.

Comment: If you don't need to use `hashHistory`, use `BrowserHistory`. Check out the examples in the documentation and see how connected router is setup: https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router. Specifically, look at the `ConfigureStore.js` file.